# Why do all auto created urls in my multilingual site cause a Page not found?

Tags: 7, redirection

I have a multilingual site, using Drupal core 7.43 and the [Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) module, and the [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module (and aliases are auto created without any problems).

Creating content translation I've got such problem: all auto created url aliases don't work.

When I change site language (as visitor) all seems Ok, I see all content has been translated. But if I (as a logged in user which is also an        administrator) try to open an article (for example), or any other translated content, I am always getting "***Page Not Found***". Auto created url leads nowhere.

What is wrong?

**Note**: When I am manually adding redirect (eg. from `mysite/content/myarticle_1` to `node/122`), I am getting error "*You are attempting to redirect the page to itself. This will result in an infinite loop.*" When I change article language from native to "All languages" then redirect could be saved and works as it should be.

Comment: How are you creating those urls for "auto created url aliases"? About your " if I try to open": is that as a logged in user, or a visiotor, which I assume mean "anonymous"?

Comment: I am just creating a translation for content as usual and aliases are auto creating from node:title,Yes, I am talking about logged in user,moreover,user with administrative rights(administrator).

Comment: well, If you mean auto creation pattern - it's   "content/[node:title]". That's all. This is configuration by default. By default there wasn't Redirect module installed in my site installation. I've added Redirect by myself. Then recreated few content translations and problem leaves the same.

Comment: Do you have the [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module enabled or not?

Comment: What I'm figured out. When I am manually adding redirect(eg. from:mysite/content/myarticle_1 to: node/122) I am getting error "You are attempting to redirect the page to itself. This will result in an infinite loop." When I change article language from native  to "All languages"  then redirect could be saved and works as it should be.

Comment: Yes, Pathauto module is enabled from the box. Aliases are auto created without any problems but then they don't work. That is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check your configuration at `Configuration -> Languages -> detection and selection`: the order specified there could be what explains the current behaviour in your site.

You'd have to experiment a bit with what the exact order in your case should be. In my experience, I often get these kind of issues to work by using an order like 'URL, Default, User', and not something like 'Default, URL, User'. It could well be that that is all that's needed here ... So try to experiment a bit with the various combinations in this order to see if it helps.

**Note**: Debugging is the *art of taking away all possible causes of a problem*. So sorry upfront if this answer turns out to not be *the* solution.